# MS Access if field is <= OR >=

Tags: ms-access

I need some help. I have two fields where i write in a range for example 1,12 and 1,45. And i have a Table where the user can enter a price for example 1,32. Now i would like to check in this field if its in between the range.

I tried this already:

Preis/Liter is the field where the user enters the price

PreisRangeEins and -.-Zwei are the fields with the range

```
IIf ([Preis/Liter] < [PreisRangeEins] And [Preis/Liter] > [PreisRangeZwei])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need `Or` instead of `And`:

```
IIf ([Preis/Liter] < [PreisRangeEins] Or [Preis/Liter] > [PreisRangeZwei])
```

The condition can otherwise never be true, as the same price can not be both smaller than a `value1` and greater than a `value2` if `value1 < value2`.

The above checks whether `Preis/Liter` is **outside** the range. If you want to make sure it is **within** the range, you need to use

```
IIf ([Preis/Liter] >= [PreisRangeEins] And [Preis/Liter] <= [PreisRangeZwei])
```

Note the swapped comparison signs!

Comment: Ahhh i knew it was just a little thing :) thanks
Do you maybe know if i need to write and truepart or falsepart? Or can i simply ignore them?

Comment: You can not ignore the true/false part, but the action depends on what you want to do :-) Using `IIF` is AFAIK only useful and valid in formulae to for example change the background color or the like. If you want to use this in VBA **code** (for example to display a message box) you can not use `IIF` but need to use the `IF` statement.

Comment: Actually i want this: If the user defined the range 1,10 to 1,50 and than writes 1,05 into the Preis/Liter field it should say it's wrong blablabla if he enters 1,25 it should write into the field because its withing range

Comment: I'm not an Excel expert. I'd google for `Excel cell validation message box` or the like and if you don't find anything that helps you ask a new question here with your specific requirement.

Comment: I'm not much into Access either, but I know that SQL Server allows you to put so called "constraints" on fields so that you can reject values if they don't match a condition. Maybe the same or something similar is possible in Access, too?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the term `BETWEEN`:

```
iif([preis/Liter] BETWEEN [PreisRangeEins] AND [PreisRangeZwei],truepart,falsepart)
```